# Ejecutar un módulo luego de hacer una petición POST

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, push-notification

Estoy tratando de integrar el envío de información en tiempo real a través de **sockets** (usando **socket.io**), y el envio notificaciones *push* usando la plataforma **OneSignal**.

Ocurre que si coloco todo en el mismo módulo, no sé por que no se ejecuta el método para enviar la notificación luego que la información es enviada, o antes de enviar la información.

Si ejecuto el comando `npm start` no aparece error pero la notificación llega apenas el servidor local o remoto está en marcha, y de esta forma no quiero que suceda.

#### user.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var misocket = require('../routes/misocket');
var notificacion = require('../routes/notificacion');

/*

Si pongo esto asi, apenas envia el servidor, arranca de una vez y envia la notificacion
notificacion();

 */
/* GET users listing. sendnote*/
router.post('/sendasig', function (req, res, next) {

    console.log(misocket); //registrednote
    misocket.emit("registrar", req.body);
    //La idea es que se ejecute aqui, pero no logro hacer que esto suceda
    notificacion();
    console.log(req.body);

    res.status(200).json({
        message: "send message"
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

#### notificacion.js

```
module.exports = function () {

    var OnesignalNotificationApi = require('onesignal-notification');
    var api = new OnesignalNotificationApi('N2FkY2ZkZWQtMGQ2MS00ZTUwLTlkM2QtODA2NmE0YjBiMzQ3',
            'c4b92cce-4d59-4550-a4be-20939370e39c');

    var message = {
        it: 'Some message',
        en: 'Some message',
        es: 'Nueva Calificacion'
    };

    api.sendToAll(message, null, function (err, res) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(res);
    });

};
```

#### app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var misocket = require('./routes/misocket');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var io = require("socket.io");
var app = express();
app.io = io();

var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: 'XXX',
  consumer_secret: 'XXX',
  access_token_key: 'XXX',
  access_token_secret: 'XXX'
});


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
//app.use('/api', users);
app.post("/sendnote",function(req,res,next){

  app.io.emit("registrednote",req.body);

  res.status(200).json({
                    message  : "send message"
                });
});
//copias y modificas la ruta del post
app.post('/sendasig', function(req, res, next) {

  app.io.emit("registrar",req.body);
  res.status(200).json({
                    message  : "send message"
                });

});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


misocket.connection(app.io);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: que intentas hacer exactamente ?

Comment: luego que suceda esto, `misocket.emit("registrar",req.body);`, poder que se ejecute esto, `api.sendToAll`

Comment: ¿Haz intentado con promises?

Comment: @Jorius no, podrias responder como hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Cuando dices «No se ejecuta», literalmente el método no se ejecuta o quieres decir que no se envía la notificación?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas. Primero, no es la forma correcta de integrar express y socket.io. En realidad, no estás creando ningún servidor socket con ese código. Lo correcto es:

```
var http = require('http')
var io = require("socket.io");
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app)
var socketServer = io(server)
```

El código anterior crea un servidor usando el módulo `http` nativo de [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) y también el servidor express. Finalmente, crea un servidor socket usando el servidor recientemente creado. En este punto, ya tienes tu servidor [http](/questions/tagged/http) y [socket](/questions/tagged/socket) funcionando.

---

Otro punto es que exportas tanto `app` como `socketServer` para que sea usados por otros módulos.

```
exports.io = socketServer;
exports.app = app
```

Es muy importante que entiendas el flujo de tu aplicación, para que sepas en qué punto las dependencias de otros módulos estarán listas en otro. Por ejemplo, fíjate en lo siguiente:

**users.js**

```
var misocket = require('../app').io;
```

**app.js**

```
var users = require('./routes/users');
```

Tienes un problema de dependencias circulares. Esto significa que, cuando importas `users` en el top de tu archivo `app.js`, `users.js` intentará importar `io` de `app.js` pero obtendrá `undefined` **porque aún no ha sido creado ni exportado**. Lo que tienes que hacer aquí es acomodar tu código para que se adapte al flujo:

```
exports.io = socketServer;
...
app.use('/', require('./routes'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));
...
misocket.connection(socketServer); // pone el servidor socket en escucha
server.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started'));
exports.app = app;
```

---

El tercer problema que veo es que no entiendes el concepto de asincronía. Tu módulo `notificacion` ejecuta un código asíncrono al enviar notificaciones push vía `OneSignal`, es siempre recomendable que estas se envíen antes de enviar una respuesta http si se ejecuta dentro de una petición. Por ende, podrías convertir ese módulo para que devuelva una promesa:

```
module.exports = function() {

  var OneSignal = require('onesignal-notification');
  var api = new OneSignal('N2FkY2ZkZWQtMGQ2MS00ZTUwLTlkM2QtODA2NmE0YjBiMzQ3', 'c4b92cce-4d59-4550-a4be-20939370e39c');
  var message = {
    it: 'Some message',
    en: 'Algún mensaje',
    es: 'Nuevo mensaje',
  };

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    api.sendToAll(message, null, function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err.message);
      } else {
        resolve(res);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Esto te permitirá llevar un flujo asíncrono mucho más cómodo en `users.js`:

```
router.post('/sendasig', function (req, res) {
  misocket.emit("registrar", req.body);
  notificacion()
    .then(function(response) {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "send message"
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "send message"
      });
    });
});
```

--

Como último consejo, te recomiendo encarecidamente empezar a usar ES6+. Node.js tiene soporte muy avanzado out-of-the-box, como funciones asíncronaa (`async/await`). Utilizar ES6+ significará un mejor código, más conciso, mantenible y eficiente.

Comment: ¿ Cuanto pides por el riñón ? ¿ Aceptas *bitcoins* ? Si no está en muy mal estado, claro ;-)

Comment: @Juanjo ¡Por supuesto! El estado es muy bueno, considerando que es un hombre joven y sano (no consume alcohol ni drogas), el riñón está casi sin usar xD. 9 BTC y cerrramos :D

Comment: Y mira que el BTC ha bajado, aprovecha que ya va de subida xD

Comment: @Juanjo se viene el **Black Market**

Answer (score 0):

En [socket.io API](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-emit-eventname-args-ack) puedes ver los argumentos que le puedes pasar a la funcion emit, son nombre del evento, argumentos y callback que se ejecuta cuando se recibe la respuesta del cliente.

```
misocket.emit("registrar", req.body, function (respuesta) {
    notificacion();
});
```

Falta incluir la respuesta del cliente con el callback:

```
client.on("registrar", function (datos, callback) {
    callback('registrado');
});
```

Comment: deja pruebo ya mismo y te digo si funciona, te llevas los puntos

Comment: nada no funciona amigo

Comment: Edite la respuesta, con el callback en el cliente.

Comment: Ya mismo pruebo, dame un momento, y te digo si sirvio

Comment: error, `ReferenceError: callback is not defined
    at Socket.<anonymous> ((index):70)
    at socket.js:24
    at angular.js:19916
    at f (angular.js:6111)
    at angular.js:6390`